# Tour example questions copied from Gardening & Landscaping

Tags: discussion, site-tour

We might want to consider updating the sample question on the [Tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) page to reflect something on-topic here instead of continuing to use the copy-pasted text from [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I know want to see if we can come up with a dummy question and answer to fill this need. The hardest part will be no linking.  I'm thinking of making manual citations just for this.

Comment: Is this worth coming back to?

Comment: IMO yes, but this question didn't seem to be upvoted enough.

Answer (score 7):

There are [severe constraints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163948) on the questions/answers that can appear within the tour: short, no images, no complex formatting, two answers, an answer has a comment, has certain score, etc... The default unicorns/daisies example remains on many sites mostly because there are no eligible examples there yet. Some sites find that their expectations of answers are pretty much opposite of what the Tour expects.

The [query for possible examples](http://data.stackexchange.com/health/query/92078/possible-about-questions) comes up empty on Health, so the default example is  here to stay for a while.

(And no, it's not copied from Gardening & Landscaping because unicorns are off-topic there.)

Comment: "Gardening problems such as diagnosis and management of plant diseases and pests" is [on-topic](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there. So to the extent that unicorns are pests to plants, such a question would seem valid.

Comment: @ NormalHuman Good point, +1

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a targeted question to address our unicorn problem:

[How do I determine a target time frame for breastfeeding?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/how-do-i-determine-a-target-time-frame-for-breastfeeding)

`Len()` 395, no links no formatting.  Even got two sources in to show researched.  I don't think I can be the one to answer the question looking at the search quarry, so someone else needs to squeeze out an answer that meets the same guidelines.

Comment: Also while we're "gaming" the system to make an ideal question-answer set, I can try to post an answer here for someone to put down (someone else re-posting the question then closing it seems harder).  Only if people are interested, however.